# ClusterReceptionistExtension doesn't register Subscriber

Tags: akka, akka-cluster

I am trying to use akka pub-sub with in our application. I have a play application which is part of akka cluster. I want to use akka cluster-client to make make this application listen/subscribe to topics and messages will be published from other applications.

Cluster/Subscriber side code [within Play application]

```
class MyRealtimeActor extends Actor {
    import DistributedPubSubMediator.{ Subscribe, SubscribeAck }

    def receive = {
        case SubscribeAck(Subscribe("metrics", _)) => {
        Logger.info("SUBSCRIBED TO MESSAGES")
        context become ready
        }
    }

    def ready: Actor.Receive = {
        case m => {
        Logger.info("RECEIVED MESSAGE " + m)
        }
    }

}
```

and I instantiate like this in Global

```
val cluster: ActorSystem = ActorSystem("ClusterSystem")
val metricsActor = Global.cluster.actorOf(Props(new MyRealtimeActor), "metricsActor")
ClusterReceptionistExtension(cluster).registerSubscriber("metrics", metricsActor)
```

and the conf file has the following

```
akka {
    actor {
        provider = "akka.cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider"
        extensions = ["akka.contrib.pattern.DistributedPubSubExtension",
        "akka.contrib.pattern.ClusterReceptionistExtension"]
    }
    remote {
        log-remote-lifecycle-events = off
        netty.tcp {
        hostname = "127.0.0.1"
        port = 2551
    }
}

cluster {
    seed-nodes = [
    "akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2551"
    ]

    auto-down-unreachable-after = 10s
}
```

When is start the play application i can see the following log

```
 [INFO] [11/06/2013 17:48:42.926] [ClusterSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3]     [Cluster(akka://ClusterSystem)] Cluster Node [akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2551] - Node [akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2551] is JOINING, roles []
 [INFO] [11/06/2013 17:48:42.942] [ClusterSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] [akka://ClusterSystem/deadLetters] Message [akka.contrib.pattern.DistributedPubSubMediator$SubscribeAck] from Actor[akka://ClusterSystem/user/distributedPubSubMediator#1608017981] to Actor[akka://ClusterSystem/deadLetters] was not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
```

Would like to know why the actor is not properly subscribed ? I am expecting it to print SUBSCRIBED TO MESSAGES

Comment: Is your metricsActor started correctly? It seems like the mediator is sending the ack directly to dead letters.

Could you try change the log level to debug?

Comment: I have captured the logs here - https://gist.github.com/vishaljohn/7352736. I can clearly see that my actor is started.

Comment: @Björn Antonsson Any pointers would be of great help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is that the SubscribeAck is sent to the sender of the Subscribe message and not the actor in the Subscribe message. To get the SubscribeAck sent to the metricsActor, it would have to send the Subscribe itself, and directly to the mediator.

The receptionist is used by the cluster client code, and you shouldn’t use that to subscribe your actors normally.